# How to create a double outline border?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am writing my CSS in JS using `radium` and thus, I can't use pseudo classes `:after` and `:before` (which would have been made the solution very simple). How should I create the border as show in the below diagram.

[image]

Here, grey border is the same color as the main background color, which is separated by white border.

So far my CSS looks like this

```
upload: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "0",
    top: "0",
    overflow: "hidden",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    backgroundColor: "#ccdde5",
    cursor: "pointer"
}
```

which will produce the output like this

[image]

Comment: Use a white border and your _bluish_ box-shadow - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amkda8hk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using nested box-shadows:

```css
.circle-border-2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ccdde5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px  white, 
              0 0 0 10px #ccdde5;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border-2"></div>
```

This approach even allows you to add multible borders:

```css
.circle-unicorn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #9932FF, 
              0 0 0 10px #B231FD, 
              0 0 0 15px #FF31EB,
              0 0 0 20px #FF3291,
              0 0 0 25px #FE3030,
              0 0 0 30px #FE6031,
              0 0 0 35px #FFC132,
              0 0 0 40px #30FE5B,
              0 0 0 45px #5230FF,
              0 0 0 50px #3E25BF;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-unicorn"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**HaNdTriX**'s answer is a good one.
Another possible solution:

```css
.circle-shadow-border {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: gray;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white inset;
  border: solid 5px gray;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-shadow-border"></div>
```

Or use `background-clip: content-box;`:

```css
.circle-border-backclip {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 5px gray;
  padding: 5px;
  background-clip: content-box; /* support: IE9+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border-backclip"></div>
```

for more information you could see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily, by simply adding an background color, padding and solid border.

I created a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/o81rre69/

```
    .upload {
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background: #FFF;
        border: 3px solid #BBB;
    }
```

Hope it helps!